# Cannot resolve symbol variable getSelectedIndex

Tags: java, oop, cannot-find-symbol

I was having trouble trying to copy and paste the code here it said something about having unformatted?? i dont know its my first time but here is the troublesome code i'll link a pastebin so you can see too

whole code: http://pastebin.com/p6RQiSLz

the problematic code:

```
    //City (JList with txtfield)

    pane.add(lblCity);
    lblCity.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblCity.setBounds(5,260,80,25);

    pane.add(list);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    list.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    list.setBounds(90,260,150,100);
    list.setEnabled(false);
    pane.add(txtCity);
    txtCity.setBounds(90,380,150,25);

//================================TROUBLED BLOCK OF CODE============================================

    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent er){
            txtCity.setText(listCity[listCity.getSelectedIndex]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: getSelectedIndex should me a method, so "getSelectedIndex()"?

Comment: doesn't work... tried it

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: its "Cannot resolve symbol variable getSelectedIndex" its the title :/ take a look at the paste bin the whole code is there

Comment: ok, so it's an array. you probably want something like "listCity[list.getSelectedIndex()]".

Comment: that worked thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listCity is an array and arrays don't have getSelectedIndex properties, there isn't even the concept of a "selected element" for arrays. You probably want the item that's selected on the JList made from listCity, so instead of listCity.getSelectedIndex, try list.getSelectedIndex(). That should at least compile.

Comment: yeah it worked it seems I had 2 problems first was I was only using getSelectedIndex and I was referring to the wrong variable...

Comment: @OscarCubz Cool, glad it worked. Not to shill for reputation or anything :-), but if an answer's useful and answers the question, it's polite to upvote it and mark it as answering the question.

Comment: how exactly do I do that lol I just started here like not 30mins ago XD

Comment: @OscarCubz To upvote, click the up arrow above the 0 to the left of the answer.